# Facebook access token - using it inside Flash after getting it from Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, flash

I'm new to Facebook development and I'm trying to learn how to use the AS3 Facebook API from Adobe, but I'm having some issues.

The main problem is that I'm doing the authentication through Javascript. I successfully get the Access Token and send it to my Flash app through ExternalInterface. The problem lies in the fact that I don't understand how I can start using the Facebook API within Flex now that I have already authenticated through JS.

I try using the Facebook.init method, but the callback never fires. This is what I'm using after I have made sure that the session connection with Facebook was successful:

> Facebook.init(APP_ID, callback, null, accessToken);

The null value is the options parameter, which is optional and the accessToken value is the one retrieved from Javascript, which is valid. But as I said before the callback never fires.

To be honest I don't know if this is the way to start working inside Flash after I did the OAuth process through Javascript, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Charles or another debug proxy to see if you're getting an error response from Facebook? Are your application settings configured to use OAuth 2.0?

Comment: At least in Javascript I can see the responses coming through just fine. I even make a "/me" request before alerting Flash and the response object has all the correct user info. I also have oauth set to true in the JS. But the init method inside Flash won't fire the callback. I can't even see if I'm getting a fail object.

Comment: Also, I don't get any error from Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it resolved.

Inside my Flash app I added an options object to pass to the init method, like this one:

> var _options:* = {channelUrl  : CHANNEL_URL,
>               status  : false,
>               oauth       : true  };

So my init looks like this:

> Facebook.init(APP_ID, callbackMethod, options, validAccessToken);

Not sure if all the properties are necessary in the object, but it worked.

In the HTML, I used the following Embed method(as some others seem to cause problems):

> var flashvars = {};
>               var params = {};
>               var attributes = {};
>               params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
>               swfobject.embedSWF("NestleEaster.swf", "myAlternativeContent", "743", "743", "9.0.0", flashvars, params, attributes, {name:"flashContent"});

Tha's pretty much it. Now I can use the API freely inside my Flash app. Hopefully this helps someone else.